# Velocity's FileResourceLoader can't find resources

Tags: java, velocity

I use Velocity in order to load email templates. Those templates are first downloaded from the FTP server and then saved as temporary files.

However, when I try to load the template I get an exception:
`org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'C:\Users\someUsername\AppData\Local\Temp\template1526050996884865454.html'`

And I'm sure the file is there and it's not damaged.

That's how I try to load the template:

`template = velocityEngine.getTemplate(tempFile.getCanonicalPath());`

Here's the velocity.properties file that I load (and I've checked that the properties are properly initialized!)

```
file.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
file.resource.loader=file
file.resource.loader.path=.
```

So where lies the problem? Is it because AppData folder is hidden by default?

Comment: Seems to me your `.path` property is wrong.

Comment: I've tried without specifying the `.path` property too. It just defaults to this value anyway. Also according to http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/developer-guide.html#configurationexamples this value is correct.

Comment: Correct but "." is current directory

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229197/where-does-velocity-search-for-the-template/33061442#33061442 , you might need to call `Velocity.init()` . I had a similar issue. My answer is that long explaination with no points!

Comment: @RC. You were right! I tried specifying the path before so I didn't think it would help now. What I didn't notice was the fact that my `\\` characters were not escaped so it malformed the path. If you would create an answer I would gladly upvote and accept it.

Comment: @Arqan, I did nothing, may I suggest **you** add an answer for future reader and accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a design flaw in the Velocity `FileResourceLoader`. Basically if your `file.resource.loader.path` is anything other than an empty string, it'll mangle any absolute paths handed to it as the `file`. Additionally it has Unix/Linux-specific code to "nip off" (paraphrasing the actual code comment) an absolute file-path handed to it (Giving a broken absolute path re-rooted to the current `path` setting).

**Solution 1:**
Set the `file.resource.loader.path` to an empty string (prior to `init()`) and use absolute file-paths as the `file` parameter

```
ve.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", "");
ve.init();
Template template = ve.getTemplate("C:\\Users\\someUsername\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\template1526050996884865454.html");
```

**Solution 2:** Set the `path` to be the common root for your temp files and only hand it paths relative to that:

```
ve.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", "C:\\Users\\someUsername\\AppData\\Local\\Temp");
ve.init();
Template template = ve.getTemplate("template1526050996884865454.html");
```

Ultimately I think the `FileResourceLoader` class would be better if it detected any absolute path handed to it as a file-name and not try to mash the `path` setting into it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MOles's answer, there is a third solution.

**Solution 3**: Configure more than one file resource loader: one for absolute resources and one for relative ones. Something like this:

```
resource.loader=absolute-file, relative-file
absolute-file.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
absolute-file.resource.loader.path=
relative-file.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
relative-file.resource.loader.path=.
```

This will allow files to be loaded either relatively *or* absolutely, since FileResourceLoader evidently gets confused when you try to use a single instance for either type of path.